# Spring Batch - How to read from One Table and Write Data into two different table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm using `Spring Boot and Spring Batch` to read data from One table of source database table and split the data and write it into two tables of target database.

I choose to use `CompositeItemWriter` for this, but `CompositeItemWriter<?>` only one type. I want to write few fields in one table and other fields into another table.

Say: OLD Customer and NEW Customer.

Error:

> The constructor CustomerClassifier(JdbcBatchItemWriter, JdbcBatchItemWriter) is undefined

**ClassifierCompositeItemApplication.java**

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication
public class ClassifierCompositeItemApplication {

private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

public ClassifierCompositeItemApplication(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
    this.jobBuilderFactory = jobs;
    this.stepBuilderFactory = steps;
}


@Value("classpath:input/customer.csv")
private Resource inputResource;

@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemReader<Customer> classifierCompositeWriterItemReader() {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Customer>()
            .name("customerFileReader")
            .resource(inputResource).delimited()
            .names(new String[] { "firstName", "middleInitial", "lastName", "address", "city", "state", "zip" })
            .targetType(Customer.class)
            .build();
}


@Bean
public ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<Customer> compositeItemWriter() throws IOException {
    final Classifier<Customer, ItemWriter<? super Customer>> classifier = new CustomerClassifier(
            this.customer1(null), this.customer2(null));

    return new ClassifierCompositeItemWriterBuilder<Customer>().classifier(classifier).build();
}



@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Customer> customer1(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Customer>()
            .namedParametersJdbcTemplate(new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource))
            .sql("INSERT INTO TBL_CUSTOMER_WRITER (firstname, middleinitial, lastname, address, city, " + "state, "
                    + "zipcode) " + "VALUES(:firstName, " + ":middleInitial, " + ":lastName, " + ":address, "
                    + ":city, " + ":state, " + ":zip)")
            .beanMapped().build();
}



@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<NewCustomer> customer2(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<NewCustomer>()
            .namedParametersJdbcTemplate(new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource))
            .sql("INSERT INTO TBL_CUSTOMER_WRITER (firstname, middleinitial, lastname, address, city, " + "state, "
                    + "zipcode) " + "VALUES(:firstName, " + ":middleInitial, " + ":lastName, " + ":address, "
                    + ":city, " + ":state, " + ":zip)")
            .beanMapped().build();
}



@Bean
public Step classifierCompositeWriterStep() throws IOException {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("compositeWriterStep")
            .<Customer, Customer>chunk(10)
            .reader(this.classifierCompositeWriterItemReader())
            .writer(this.compositeItemWriter())
            .stream(this.customer1(null))
            .stream(this.customer2(null))
            .build();
}


@Bean
public Job classifierCompositeWriterJob() throws IOException {
    return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("compositeWriterJob").start(this.classifierCompositeWriterStep()).build();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ClassifierCompositeItemApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

**CustomerClassifier.java**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomerClassifier implements Classifier<Customer, ItemWriter<? super Customer>> {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private final ItemWriter<Customer> customer1;
private final ItemWriter<Customer> customer2;

@Override
public ItemWriter<? super Customer> classify(Customer customer) {
    if (customer.getState().matches("^[A-M].*")) {
        return customer1;
    } else {
        return customer2;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I added an answer. Did it help?

Comment: I will try this and let you know. Do you've sample example ?

Comment: You can find an example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriterTests.java

Comment: I am not able to classify into Customer and NewCustomer. Could you please guide ?

Comment: As mentioned in the comment of my answer, you don't need this NewCustomer class. I added a complete example of how to use the classifier composite item writer to classifiy items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [ClassifierCompositeItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html). This composite writer is designed to classify items and call a delegate item writer for each class.

So in your case, you can have am item writer for old customers and another one for new customers and warp them in a classifier item writer. You can use one of the `Classifier` implementations provided by Spring or create a custom one (for example an item processor cam flag your items as old/new and the classifier uses this flag to classify them).

EDIT: Add an example:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.builder.ClassifierCompositeItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.classify.Classifier;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJob {

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Customer> itemReader() {
        return new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(new Customer("foo"), new Customer("bar")));
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Customer> fooWriter() {
        return items -> {
            for (Customer item : items) {
                System.out.println("foo writer: item " + item.name);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Customer> barWriter() {
        return items -> {
            for (Customer item : items) {
                System.out.println("bar writer: item " + item.name);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<Customer> classifierCompositeItemWriter() {
        final Classifier<Customer, ItemWriter<? super Customer>> classifier = 
                new CustomerClassifier(this.fooWriter(), this.barWriter());

        return new ClassifierCompositeItemWriterBuilder<Customer>()
                .classifier(classifier)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(steps.get("step")
                        .<Customer, Customer>chunk(5)
                        .reader(itemReader())
                        .writer(classifierCompositeItemWriter())
                        .build())
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJob.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
    }

    static class Customer {
        String name;

        public Customer(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    static class CustomerClassifier implements Classifier<Customer, ItemWriter<? super Customer>> {

        private ItemWriter<? super Customer> fooItemWriter;
        private ItemWriter<? super Customer> barItemWriter;

        public CustomerClassifier(ItemWriter<? super Customer> fooItemWriter, ItemWriter<? super Customer> barItemWriter) {
            this.fooItemWriter = fooItemWriter;
            this.barItemWriter = barItemWriter;
        }

        @Override
        public ItemWriter<? super Customer> classify(Customer customer) {
            return customer.name.startsWith("f") ? fooItemWriter : barItemWriter;
        }
    }

}
```

This prints:

```
foo writer: item foo
bar writer: item bar
```

Comment: This is where I am struggling, I've updated my code

Comment: You did not share the code of `CustomerClassifier`, how do you classify items? You don't need this `NewCustomer` class. Moreover, you said you want to write to two different tables but both your jdbc writers are configured to write to the same table `TBL_CUSTOMER_WRITER`. Is this intended or is it a typo?

Comment: Again, no need to use different accounts to ask similar/same/related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62415019/the-method-streamitemstream-in-the-type-abstracttaskletstepbuildersimplestepb. You could have added that detail here which would have been way more efficient for everyone.

Comment: Thats why colluege who posted the question.  Everyone has curiocity to get the issues resolved. I've added the CustomerClassifier class. Hope you will share working code now. I apologized for inconvenience

Comment: Please format your question correctly, your code is unreadable.

Comment: Done, Could you please guide me now ?

Comment: I added a complete example. You need to adapt it if you really need an item stream.

Comment: Thanks, my requirement is I want to classify data and load it into two different tables, this solution works for only one table. Could you please guide accordingly ?

Comment: change fooWriter to a JdbcBatchItemWriter that writes to one table and barWriter to JdbcBatchItemWriter that writes to another table

Comment: Right, I can do that, use Customer in one JdbcBatchItemWriter, but can't use different class NewCustomer for another JdbcBatchItemWriter class. :(

Comment: That's not classifying items of the same type, that's different item types, which is a completely different story.. So please accept this answer which answers your initial question and ask a different question with all the details needed.