# Spring Batch - Classify items into different item types

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Taking a reference from the link: [Spring Batch - How to read from One Table and Write Data into two different table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62328301/spring-batch-how-to-read-from-one-table-and-write-data-into-two-different-tabl), actually I wanted to classify the items into different item types altogether.

Here I want to classify the items into `Customer` Table and `NewCustomer` table based on various conditions, so that I can save the data into two different tables.

Here is the my sample code which doesn't seem to be working well.

ClassifierCompositeItemApplication.java

```
@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication
public class ClassifierCompositeItemApplication {

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Value("classpath:input/customer.csv")
    private Resource inputResource;

    public ClassifierCompositeItemApplication(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobs;
        this.stepBuilderFactory = steps;
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public FlatFileItemReader<Customer> classifierCompositeWriterItemReader() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Customer>()
                .name("customerFileReader")
                .resource(inputResource)
                .delimited()
                .names(new String[] { "firstName", "middleInitial", "lastName", "address", "city", "state", "zip" })
                .targetType(Customer.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<Customer> compositeItemWriter() throws IOException {
        final Classifier<Customer, ItemWriter<? super Customer>> classifier = new CustomerClassifier(
                this.customer1(), this.customer2());

        return new ClassifierCompositeItemWriterBuilder<Customer>()
                .classifier(classifier)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemStreamWriter<Customer> customer1() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Customer #1");
        return new ItemStreamWriter<Customer>() {

            @Override
            public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {

            }

            @Override
            public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {

            }

            @Override
            public void close() throws ItemStreamException {

            }

            @Override
            public void write(List<? extends Customer> items) throws Exception {
                for (Customer customer : items) {
                    System.out.println(customer);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemStreamWriter<Customer> customer2() {
        System.out.println("Customer #2");
        return new ItemStreamWriter<Customer>() {

            @Override
            public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {

            }

            @Override
            public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {

            }

            @Override
            public void close() throws ItemStreamException {

            }

            @Override
            public void write(List<? extends Customer> items) throws Exception {
                for (Customer customer : items) {
                    System.out.println(customer);
                }
            }
        };
    }


    @Bean
    public Step classifierCompositeWriterStep() throws IOException {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("compositeWriterStep")
                .<Customer, Customer>chunk(10)
                .reader(this.classifierCompositeWriterItemReader())
                .writer(this.compositeItemWriter())
                .stream(this.customer1())
                .stream(this.customer2())
                .build();

    }


    @Bean
    public Job classifierCompositeWriterJob() throws IOException {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("compositeWriterJob")
                .start(this.classifierCompositeWriterStep())
                .build();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClassifierCompositeItemApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

CustomerClassifier.java

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CustomerClassifier implements Classifier<Customer, ItemWriter<? super Customer>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private ItemWriter<Customer> fileItemWriter;
    private ItemWriter<Customer> jdbcItemWriter;

    @Override
    public ItemWriter<? super Customer> classify(Customer customer) {
        if (customer.getState().matches("^[A-M].*")) {
            return fileItemWriter;
        } else {
            return jdbcItemWriter;
        }
    }
}
```

Customer.java

```
public class Customer implements Serializable {

    private String firstName;
    private String middleInitial;
    private String lastName;
    ....
    ....
    //
}
```

NewCustomer.java

```
public class NewCustomer implements Serializable {

    private String firstName;
    private String middleInitial;
    private String lastName;
    ....
    ....
    // All different fields
}
```

Comment: `// All different fields` where do all these fields come from in `NewCustomer`? How do `Customer` objects read by your item reader get transformed to `NewCustomer` objects?

Comment: From Reader, say reader has 10 fields, 5 fields will go into Customer table and other 5 fields will go into NewCustomer table

Comment: In that case, you don't need this `NewCustomer` object and this classifier. A composite writer is enough with two jdbc writers: one does `insert into customer field1, .. field5` and the other one does `insert into new_customer field6, ... field 10`. Fields 1 to 10 come from `Customer` object returned by your reader.

Comment: Great, Thanks, Could you please show some code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From Reader, say reader has 10 fields, 5 fields will go into Customer table and other 5 fields will go into NewCustomer table

In that case, you don't need this `NewCustomer` object and this classifier. A composite writer is enough with two jdbc writers: one does insert into `customer` field1, .. field5 and the other one does insert into `new_customer` field6, ... field 10. Fields 1 to 10 come from `Customer` object returned by your reader.

> Great, Thanks, Could you please show some code ?

First, create two jdbc writers, each one should insert in a given table:

```
@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Customer> writer1(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Customer>()
            .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
            .sql("INSERT INTO CUSTOMER (field1, field2) VALUES (:field1, :field2)")
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Customer> writer2(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Customer>()
            .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
            .sql("INSERT INTO NEW_CUSTOMER (field3, field4) VALUES (:field3, :field4)")
            .dataSource(dataSource)
            .build();
}
```

Then compose them in a composite writer:

```
@Bean
public CompositeItemWriter<Customer> compositeItemWriter(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new CompositeItemWriterBuilder<Customer>()
            .delegates(Arrays.asList(writer1(dataSource), writer2(dataSource)))
            .build();
}
```

Obviously, `Customer` object returned by your reader should have `field1` .. `field4`.

Comment: Great Thanks, I will try and let you know